# Wordpress - Wrong Redirect URL after make any payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, web-hosting

I'm using WC 2.0.16, with the latest version of WP. I am testing WC with many payment gateway such as cheque payment, cash on delivery, and etc. The only issue I'm having is when the user finishes a purchase and is being redirected back to my site, they are sent to a page with an incorrect address such as "http://galerigadget.com/payment/?key=order_560bb443d3fed&order=9004" (or "http://galerigadget.com/payment/") and just got blank screen.

I already tried everything to purchase a product with all payment gateways from my website still got same error like above.

Why is WooCommerce or the payment gateways adding the 'http://galerigadget.com/payment/' to the head of the URL? And how can it be removed? Any help would be greatly appreciated, as the authors don't seem to be very helpful with support.

I can't update WC to latest version because will break my current theme.

You can reproduce this bug with try to buy a product from my website: http://galerigadget.com/product/lenovo-s60/

Comment: I *strongly* advise you to update WooCommerce. WooCommerce is on version 2.4.7, meaning you are 4 semi-major updates behind. Spend the time fixing your theme and then come back if you are still having issues.

Comment: @helgatheviking ok I will try